# $T:\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ is linear and $\ker(T-aI)=\ker(T-aI)^n , \forall a\in \mathbb C$ , then $T$ diagonalizable ?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

If $T:\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ is a linear transform such that $\ker(T-aI)=\ker(T-aI)^n , \forall a\in \mathbb C$ , then is $T$ diagonalizable ?

Comment: Do you know about jordan normal form?

Comment: @GitGud: No , can we do without it ?

Comment: Probably. Do you know of such things as algebraic and geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues?

Comment: @GitGud: Yes, I know algebraic and geometric multiplicities

Answer (score 0):

Note that for Any $a \in \Bbb C$, $\dim\ker(T - aI)$ is the geometric multiplicity of $a$ (as an eigenvalue of $T$), whereas $\dim\ker(T-aI)^n$ will always be the algebraic multiplicity of $a$.

Comment: How is $\dim \ker (T-aI)^n$ the algebraic multiplicity of $a$ ?

Comment: @user123733 that's a long story, depending on what you already know.  You apparently don't know about Jordan normal form, but do you know about generalized eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes , I know about generalized eigenvectors

Comment: Note that $\dim \ker(T - aI)^n$ is the number of *generalized* eigenvectors associated with $a$.